# I am new to pyspark. I am getting Error during training a keras model using spark dataframe. Please let me know any suggestion

Tags: python, apache-spark, keras, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

```py
data=spark.read.csv("hdfs://ip-10-0-1-20.ec2.internal:8020/user/biggatcdh1/LALR.csv",inferSchema=True,header=True) for reading data X=data.drop("redshift")
X.show()
y=data.select('redshift')

X_train,X_test=X.randomSplit([0.8, 0.2])
y_train,y_test=y.randomSplit([0.8, 0.2])

import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
import timeit
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(output_dim = 512, kernel_initializer='normal',input_dim = 32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(256, kernel_initializer='normal',activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(256, kernel_initializer='normal',activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(256, kernel_initializer='normal',activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal',activation='linear'))
model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer='adagrad', metrics=['mae'])
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I am a bit stuck because I am getting the following error: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'values'`. Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: what is x_train and y_train?

Comment: Training data (spark dataframe)

Comment: why don't you show it in your question?

Comment: data=spark.read.csv("hdfs://ip-10-0-1-20.ec2.internal:8020/user/biggatcdh1/LALR.csv",inferSchema=True,header=True) for reading data  X=data.drop("redshift")
X.show()
y=data.select('redshift')
y.show()  X_train,X_test=X.randomSplit([0.8, 0.2])
y_train,y_test=y.randomSplit([0.8, 0.2])